# How do I create a DynamicMarker in vue composition api with custom html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ace-editor

I am trying to implement a code editor with remote users and currently I have a basic code Editor component like this.

```
...
<script setup>
   import ace, { Range } from 'ace-builds'
   import "ace-builds/webpack-resolver";
   import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/snippets/javascript'
   import { reactive, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

   const ace_text_area = ref(null)
   const props = defineProps({ value: String })
   const state = reactive({
      aceEditor:null,
      value:""
   })


   onMounted(()=>{
     state.value = props.value
     state.aceEditor = ace.edit(ace_text_area.value, {value: state.value});
   })
</script>
```

How do I add a remote user using addDynamicMarker ?

Comment: you can use code from cloud9 as a guide https://github.com/c9/core/blob/master/plugins/c9.ide.collab/cursor_layer.js

Comment: I read the documentation and I figured out I may be able to use [ace-collab-ext[(https://github.com/convergencelabs/ace-collab-ext) even without convergence and I hope I am right